# Encoded MDB tables and contents

Tags: c#, ms-access, vb6, encryption

I have a very old VB 16-bit application which works with .MDB file because there is also an .MDA file - because of that I am guessing it is made using access 2.0. Need to get our tables, relations and content out.  Table data is in "Danish" language.

My boss does have copyrights but no Admin username and pwd. Application runs good, meaning application is able to connect to MDB file and work with it.  I am running it on Windows 7 32-bit machine.

It seems that the database is encoded. Came to know they use RC4 encoding and .MDB header contains key for it.

Is there a way to get table and data out from encoded .MDB. I have tried my mdb unlock tools most of them do not recognize that it is .mdb, but the application works.

I am desperate to find a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Came to know they use RC4 encoding and .MDB header contains key for
> it. Is there a way to get tablet and data out from encoded .MDB.

You have to strip everything out of the Access Database file using Object Model code. Here is a script to extract data from a *corrupt* Access Database:

```
   Function FilterDB(strFilePath As String)
   Dim objAccess As Object
   Dim strFolder As String
   Dim strCurrentFile As String
   Dim strCurrentObject As String
   Dim strFilteredDB As String

   Dim fs
   Dim Ref
   Dim f As Object
   Dim objtype As AcObjectType

   Dim objAllObjects As New Collection
   Dim objObjectGroup As Object
   Dim intObjType As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim intRefNum As Integer

   Dim RefItem As Reference
   Dim arrayRefs() As String

   Dim strErrMsg As String

   'Open the source database
   Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application.10")

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strFilePath, False

   strFolder = Left(strFilePath, InStrRev(strFilePath, "\", Len(strFilePath)))
   strFilteredDB = Left(strFilePath, Len(strFilePath) - 4) & "filtered.mdb"

   With objAllObjects
       .Add objAccess.CurrentData.AllQueries
       .Add objAccess.CurrentProject.AllForms
       .Add objAccess.CurrentProject.AllReports
       .Add objAccess.CurrentProject.AllMacros
       .Add objAccess.CurrentProject.AllModules
       .Add objAccess.CurrentProject.AllDataAccessPages
   End With

   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If Not fs.folderexists(strFolder & "\texttmp") Then
       fs.CreateFolder (strFolder & "\texttmp")
   End If

   For i = 1 To objAllObjects.Count

       If objAllObjects(i).Count > 0 Then
           For j = 0 To objAllObjects(i).Count - 1
              
              Set objObjectGroup = objAllObjects(i)
    
              strCurrentObject = objObjectGroup(j).Name
              intObjType = objObjectGroup(j).Type
              objAccess.SaveAsText intObjType, strCurrentObject, _
              strFolder & "texttmp\" & strCurrentObject & intObjType & ".txt"
         
           Next j
       End If
       
   Next i
    
   'Bring in All the references
   On Error Resume Next
         
   ReDim arrayRefs(objAccess.References.Count - 1, 2) As String
         
   For Each RefItem In objAccess.References()
       If Not IsError(RefItem.Name) Then
            
           arrayRefs(intRefNum, 0) = RefItem.Name
           arrayRefs(intRefNum, 1) = RefItem.FullPath
           intRefNum = intRefNum + 1
           
       End If
   Next RefItem

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
   Debug.Print ""
   objAccess.Quit
   Set objAccess = Nothing

   Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

   objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase strFilteredDB

   'Finds the first occurrence of a text file in the
   'texttmp folder.
   strCurrentFile = Dir(strFolder & "\texttmp" & "\*.txt")
          
   'Count the files in the folder.
   Set f = fs.GetFolder(strFolder)
          
   'Check to see if the folder is empty.
   'If not, load in all the files from there
   If f.Files.Count <> 0 Then

   Do Until strCurrentFile = ""
      intObjType = Mid(strCurrentFile, Len(strCurrentFile) - 4, 1)
      objAccess.LoadFromText intObjType, _
      Left(strCurrentFile, Len(strCurrentFile) - 5), _
      strFolder & "\texttmp\" & strCurrentFile
      strCurrentFile = Dir
   Loop
   End If
          

   On Error Resume Next

   For i = 0 To UBound(arrayRefs())

       Set Ref = objAccess.References.AddFromFile(arrayRefs(i, 1))
       
   Next i

   MsgBox "Finished creating filtered file:" & Chr(10) _
   & objAccess.CurrentProject.FullName & "."

FunctionEnd:

   On Error Resume Next
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If fs.folderexists(strFolder & "\texttmp") Then
       fs.deletefolder (strFolder & "\texttmp")
   End If

   objAccess.Quit
   Set objAccess = Nothing
   Set f = Nothing

   Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

   Select Case Err.Number

       Case 58, 7866
       strErrMsg = "The path\file name " & strFilePath _
           & " may be incorrect or the " _
           & Chr(10) & " database is opened exclusively by someone else." _
           & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
           "Please insure your path and file name are correct " _
           & Chr(10) & "and the database is not open."

       Case 7865
       strErrMsg = "The follwing database:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
           & strFilteredDB & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
           & "already exists." _
           & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
           " Please rename, move, or delete it before running" _
           & "the FilterDB function."

       Case Else
       strErrMsg = "Access Error #" & Err.Number & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
       Err.Description
           
   End Select

   MsgBox strErrMsg

   GoTo FunctionEnd

   End Function
```

> I had to use this code today. You have to make a copy of the database, then paste the above code in a module and from the Immediate Window run mod.FilterDB("E:\PathToTheCopy.mdb")

Comment: Hi Jeremy,  I tried above code, it comes with an error - either path is incorrect or exclusively opened exclusively by someone else. I want to give some more information I have decompiled Application to see if can get any clues.

Comment: There is a function fn007A SetDefaultWorkspace fn007A(1, gv0042), fn007A(2, gv0042)
ôÖki¼§eü³®Ëâ¨U%þêæ»&þ¸*-¾m,5ä

Comment: When I tried above code I am pretty sure it in that path and not open by any other application as I tried by rebooting  and system running this code as first thing.

Comment: @Jermey could you pls look i worte some comments

Comment: Run that code as a Function in a Module from with MS Access VBA... open MS Access, press Alt + F11, right click project > new Module, paste in the code and press F8

Comment: @Jermey Yes I could run code in access 2003. it runs an comes up with "Path may be incorrect or database is exclusively opened by another program". sure path is correct and file is not opened by other program. Does above code used for ENCODED MDB file.

Comment: I had to use this code today. You have to make a copy of the database, then paste the above code in a module and from the Immediate Window run `mod.FilterDB("E:\PathToTheCopy.mdb")`