# MS Access Macro/VBA Non-Sense

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a fairly complex database that has worked for quite a while. Today I went to troubleshoot something and I got a non-sensical error.

In my macro, first I create detail tables. Then I number each row sequentially in the detail table with a VBA script. Then I create a summarized version of that table including the just the key info like SKU and row number. (The rest of the details are added back later using the row number). The numbering script is working. The detail tables have the row numbers. However the summary table does not have the row numbers after running the macro. If I manually click the queries to add the summary tables, the numbers magically appear.

Please help. This database has worked for over a year without this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it sounds like its corrupt. MS Access uses the Jet Engine which is known for bloating dB size and quite easily becoming corrupt.

You can see by the odd behaviour, the program is having trouble with the underlying file. If you open a new Access DB it won't exhibit the same problems.

The best bet is to recreate the dB from scratch or port it to SQL Server, PostGres, MySQL, SqlLite etc and put the application logic in a program - even if its a VB6 app, though I'd recommend .Net.

I've got the code to strip out every thing and recreate the MS Access dB here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16158027/495455